# What does 'a time' in 'once upon a time' stand for?

Tags: phrase-origin

Practically all English speakers are familiar with the formula 'once upon a time', and know very well what it is used for. The relationship of the meaning of that set phrase, as a whole, to the standard meanings of its constituent words is, however, not obvious to a typical present-day speaker of the language. [A question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194584) about that relationship has already been asked on this site, but the comments then narrowed that question down to the role of *upon* in the phrase, and its other components were consequently not addressed in the answers. Rather than trying to pursue the matter in additional comments on that question, it seemed more profitable to raise here, separately, the question of what 'a time' in that phrase stands for.

The following three answers may occur to one at first, but none of them is fully convincing.

**(1)** 'A time' stands for the **moment** at which, or immediately after which, the events occurred that are described in the sentences that follow. On that interpretation, 'upon a time' conveys essentially the same information as is already conveyed by 'once'. Such a redundancy is not itself problematic, especially in a storytelling context, but, if 'upon a time' were just another way of saying 'once', one would expect the phrase as a whole to be written out as 'once, upon a time', with a comma. That, however, is not how it is usually written.

**(2)** If we assume that 'upon a time' is not merely a duplication of 'once', but that these components of the phrase convey distinct information, then it must be possible, at least in principle, for whatever occurred once upon a time to have occurred twice upon that same time, or even more times. That implies that 'a time' stand for some **period** of time that is longer than the relatively short period within it that is denoted by 'once'. It is, however, not at all clear what that period would be.

**(3)** The frustration that  one experiences as one thinks through the first two possibilities may lead one to consider the possibility that 'a time' stands for **time in general**, encompassing the whole history of the universe. That, however, would make the indefinite article puzzling, as there is no countable multiplicity of times in that sense (setting aside some far-fetched speculation and science-fiction scenarios).

So, the question is what could 'a time' in that phrase possibly stand for, if none of these interpretations is convincing. Or, is there perhaps some further argument that would make one of these three interpretations more convincing than it appears in the above summary?

Comment: I don't think the _time_ in _once upon a time_ means anything more than the _there_ in _there was a king with a beautiful daughter_. This is a fixed phrase, and the most important thing about it is its rhythm: WUN-sa-PAW-na-TIME. It says that the story is starting and it's not modern. That's enough; the rest is etymology.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I can't help noticing that your comment here is essentially the same as the two comments you made to [an earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194584/) on this topic. The responses that were made to these comments by the OP of that question apply here as well.

Comment: You're right, I'd forgotten it after 8 years, but the answer's still the same. And I don't think there's any way to explain the meaning that doesn't depend on readers' understanding.

Comment: I don't understand why you dismiss the first possibility so quickly. Writers often omit commas even when they would be appropriate, and it is easy to see how people might do so with such a common phrase as this one.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Punctuation is optional, and doesn't have to do with meaning. Clearly it was a compositional grammatical phrase at some time, in a construction where _time_ meant 'some past time' and _upon_ meant 'at'.  So, once, at some past time, there was a king, with a beautiful daughter, or not. Or once at some past time there was a king with a beautiful daughter. Commas are nothing to build a theory of meaning with.

Comment: @JohnLawler I wouldn’t go quite so far, but yes, I was trying to say something similar: most people would infer the same meaning with or without the comma there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the origin of the "once upon a time" idiom as the way to begin a fairy tale?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/466847/what-is-the-origin-of-the-once-upon-a-time-idiom-as-the-way-to-begin-a-fairy-t)

Comment: @StuartF, no, it doesn't. Although both questions are about the origins of the phrase, they are about different aspects of its origins. The other question is about **when** the phrase came to be used, while this question is about **how** its meaning was constructed out of the meanings of the words that compose it. The answers to the when-question may be relevant to the how-question, but they do not by themselves answer it.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, true, the absence of the comma is not conclusive here, but it is suggestive, particularly given that we also don't, as it were, pronounce the comma either: we usually utter the whole phrase in one breath, without a pause.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of the term does seem to have punctuation similar to your first answer:

> c1380   Sir Ferumbras (1879) 418 (MED)   Onys..oppon a day..he slow
> kynges three.

According to the OED, an obsolete definition of "upon" is "Within the space of (a specified period of time); = on prep. 8c. Obsolete."

So perhaps it is as simple as "Once, during a time," leaving the time itself unspecified/vague due to storytelling convention (e.g., "there once was a time"). In any case, it seems like on & upon have had a slippery history and have taken on the work of several different prepositions. Idioms are already sort of peculiar, so I'm unsure that a tidy answer to this exists (or at the very least it lies beyond the scope of my research).

Comment: Once, I researched the [origin of *once upon a time*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/466875/191178), which you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> The relationship of the meaning of that set phrase, as a whole, to the
> standard meanings of its constituent words is, however, not obvious to
> a typical present-day speaker of the language.

And therein lies its beauty!

We learned the meaning of "Once upon a time" as we do all for all other words and expressions: from its use. A parent or sibling utters this odd-sounding phrase and a verbal curtain rises. We are introduced to a character and a setting nothing like everyday life. Rather than a prosaic "Once there was..." or "There was once a time when..", we come to learn that "Once upon a time" is *more than the sum of its words*. This synergy is nothing less than an incantation—an *Abracadabra!* that makes a story appear. You are asking a magician to reveal how a trick is done. *Upon my word!*

Comment: This may well be why we keep the phrase in the present-day editions of fairy tales (even if their language may be modernised in other respects), in spite of our having forgotten how the phrase came to be used that way in the first place. But my question is how did this phrase come to be used this way. I assume that it was chosen because, once upon a time, it made sense to somebody, that is I assume that it is not an entirely arbitrary incantation.

Comment: "Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary," It may have sounded poetic and not prosaic to the "first user" too. It makes sense even now.